# Merge two objects in javascript ignoring undefined values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to merge two objects but I don't want to assign undefined value to defined values.

```
A = { activity: 'purchased', count: undefined, time: '09:05:33' }
B = { activity: 'purchased', count: '51', time: undefined }
```

When I try Object.assign, undefined is replacing fields that have values.

What I want

```
C = { activity: 'purchased', count: '51', time: '09:05:33' }
```

Comment: first remove the undefined `Object.keys(A).filter(key => A[key]).reduce((acc, key)  => (acc[key] = A[key], acc), {})` ones and assign.

Comment: Will `A` and `B` have same property name (i.e no extra property in any of them) and can `A` and `B` have different values of same property? If yes, them which one to assign.

Comment: I cleaned up the tags but kept the _reactjs_ tag as I guess it's because you're looking for an immutable solution?

Answer (score 4):

The **spread operator(...)** works well to merge objects, and there is a simple solution to remove undefined using **JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse()**. See below example:

```js
const A = { activity: 'purchased', count: undefined, time: '09:05:33' };
const B = { activity: 'purchased', count: '51', time: undefined };

//If you don't care about date objects then only use below method 
const C = {...JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(A)), ...JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(B))};

console.log(C);
```

Comment: This won't work with a variety of other values ([anything that's not JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/122704/1218980)), so be careful.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [lodash's merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge) command. `C = _.merge(A,B);`

Answer (score 3):

```js
let A = { activity: 'purchased', count: undefined, time: '09:05:33' }
let B = { activity: 'purchased', count: '51', time: undefined }

let C={}
Object.keys({...A,...B}).map(key=>{
C[key]=B[key]||A[key]
})
console.log(C)
```

Comment: You lose eventualy additional attributes of B

Comment: I am considering `A` and `B` both have same properties

Comment: So it is not perfect...This is not a complete merge. But it is based only on A structure

Comment: I have updated the solution to be a complete merge now. But still the question is vage. What is same property have different values, then which one to be considered.

Comment: This will replace all other falsy values in B with anything that's in A.

Answer (score 0):

You could merge the objects by having a look to the entries of the second object and take only key/value pairs without `undefined` as value.

```js
const
    merge = (a, b) => Object.assign(
        {},
        a,
        ...Object.entries(b).map(([k, v]) => v === undefined ? {} : { [k]: v })
    ),
    a = { activity: 'purchased', count: undefined, time: '09:05:33' },
    b = { activity: 'purchased', count: '51', time: undefined };

console.log(merge(a, b));
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do the same, and came up with:

```js
function assignIgnoreUndefined(...args) {
  const final = args.shift();
  args.filter(arg => !!arg).forEach(arg => {
    Object.entries(arg).forEach(nv => {
      const [ name, value ] = nv;
      if (value !== undefined) {
        final[name] = value;
      }
    });
  });
  return final;
}
```

Example usage:

```js
const A = { activity: 'purchased', count: undefined, time: '09:05:33' };
const B = { activity: 'purchased', count: '51', time: undefined };
const C = assignIgnoreUndefined({}, A, B);
console.log(C);
```

Output:

```js
{ activity: 'purchased', time: '09:05:33', count: '51' }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const A = { activity: 'purchased', count: undefined, time: '09:05:33' }
const B = { activity: 'purchased', count: '51', time: undefined }
const AKeys = Object.keys(A);
const BKeys = Object.keys(B);
const C = {};
AKeys.forEach(element=>A[element] && C[element]=A[element])
BKeys.forEach(element=>B[element] && C[element]=B[element])
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
let A = { activity: 'purchased', count: undefined, time: '09:05:33' }
let B = { activity: 'purchased', count: '51', time: undefined }

for (let a in A) {
  if (A[a] === undefined) 
    delete A[a];
}

for (let b in B) {
  if (B[b] === undefined) 
    delete B[b];
}

let c = {...A, ...B} // this will merge identical key/values

console.log(c)
```